# Как сделать так, чтобы блок с картинкой не "скакал" по высоте после загрузки картинки?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Я тут делал сайт http://emed.testing.vn.ua и заказчик недоволен: при загрузке в хроме скачет полоска под слайдером. Сайт на WordPress и грузит сразу много тяжёлых картинок.

Мне надо, чтобы ну хотя бы жёлтая линия под слайдером оставалась на своём месте от старта загрузки. Прелоадер не катит и зафиксировать высоту слайдера нельзя. Он типа меняет высоту при адаптации. Подскажите, хоть приблизительно, что можно сделать?

Comment: Просто картинку в жёлтом квадрате привяжите к родителю

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Для сохранения пропорций изображения при изменении размера окна, можно воспользоваться следующим трюком с `padding`, который позволит зарезервировать место под картинку, не указывая конкретное значение для высоты:

```css
.parent {
  padding-bottom: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%,
  height: 0;
}

.child {
  background: url('https://satyr.io/1200x768/400') 50% 50%/cover no-repeat #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Изменить размер окна для проверки вы можете в аналогичном примере на [**jsFiddle**](http://.parent%20%7B%20%20%20padding-bottom:%2033.33%25;%20%20%20position:%20relative;%20%20%20width:%20100%25,%20%20%20height:%200;%20%7D%20%20.child%20%7B%20%20%20background:%20url('https://satyr.io/1200x768/400')%2050%25%2050%25/cover%20no-repeat%20#fff;%20%20%20position:%20absolute;%20%20%20top:%200;%20%20%20right:%200;%20%20%20bottom:%200;%20%20%20left:%200;%20%7D).

Сделав так, как показано в примере, вы зарезервируете место под картинку еще до ее загрузки и полоска никуда скакать не будет. К слову, это не зависит от браузера, как вы думаете.

Что здесь происходит: `padding-bottom: 33.33%;` говорит о том, что высота картинки относится к ее ширине как один к трем. Настоящий размер картинки 1200x768 пикселей, но благодаря `50% 50%/cover` мы видим только центральную часть картинки, после того, как она была пропорциональна вписана по ширине.

Почему так происходит: `padding-bottom` **зависит от ширины блока**. Повторюсь, указывая `33.33%` процента, мы как бы говорим, что нам нужна высота, равная 1/3 от ширины. Если бы нужна была пропорция картинки `4:3`, то для `padding-bottom` нужно было бы указать значение, равное `3 / 4 * 100%` или `75%`. Если бы нужно было соотношение сторон для изображения `16:9`, то для `padding-bottom` нужно было бы указать значение, равное
`9 / 16 * 100%` или `56.25%`.

Увы, данный подход имеет недостатки. Во-первых, мы не можем использовать свойство `height` при такой комбинации. Высота должна быть равна 0, чтобы не разрушить пропорции блока, а содержимое блока должно быть абсолютно позиционировано. Во-вторых, если в слайдере используются картинки с разным соотношением сторон, то содержимое картинок, соотношение сторон которых не совпадает с выбранным, будет обрезано.

Большинство слайдеров нормально обрабатывают таким образом оформленные блоки.